# How do I find the correlation between many different samples over multiple counts?

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, multivariate-analysis, count-data

I'm new to this and I suspect my question isn't very difficult to answer, but I struggle with finding the answer.

I have a dataset like this:
[image: table]

This is just an example of the set-up I have.

I'm simply trying to find the correlation between each sample. To put it into context, say each sample is a site in nature. I count how many flowers within each site are red, green, blue etc. My goal is to see how closely related each sample is to one another.

I think I should be using some form of multiple regression, poisson or the like, but I stumble at each turn when trying to code it in R-studio (I've been thrust into this with very little prior knowledge).

Any and all help is really appreciated, I'm very much out of my depth here so I will try to clarify my issue if it isn't clear enough.

Comment: Do you have any other data available? E.g. the locations of A, B, C,... as e.g. longitude and latitude? You might be able to construct a spatial predictor of red, green and blue

Comment: Unfortunately no, all I have is a site and then counts for each variable in each site.

Comment: Since A,B,C,... are somewhat meaningless, I suspect all you can do here is use the number of (say) red in one sample to predict the number of (say) green in another. Is that all you're looking to do?

Comment: I'm looking to see how the samples A, B and C are correlated to one another based on the numbers of red, blue and green found at each site.

Comment: Search our site for [Cramer's V](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cramer*+V) or see the Wikipedia article on [contingency table measures of association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table#Measures_of_association)

Comment: Thank you! I will do that